# Invert values in Pandas data frame

Tags: pandas

is there a way I can invert values in a dataframe using Pandas? I am using data representing customers feedback. It is captured as a value from 1 to 5, 5 being the best feedback and 1 the lowest. I would like to invert it so that 1 becomes the highest score, so basically all the 5s become 1s, 4 becomes 2 and 3 stays 3. Is there a way I can achieve that? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `df['col_name'] = 5 - df['col_name']`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df['Feedback'] =6- df['Feedback']
```

Answer (score 0):

The [map function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) is used for substituting each value in a Series with another value. So, you should try:

`df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].map({5:1, 4:2, ...})`

Comment: Please consider explaining your answer. Answers with no explanation are usually tagged as low quality posts for review.